# Excel spreadsheet hyperlinks change when uploaded to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, microsoft-excel, file-conversion

I've produced an Excel table with hyperlinks in cells from sheets to other sheets. I can't share the Excel document because its confidential but the anomalies are very unusual.

One cell contains `[11]` which links to a cell in sheet `papers!A11` But when uploaded to Google Drive this appears as the words `papers!A11` instead of `[11]` as in the original Windows 10 generated XLSX file.

Then there are multiple occurrences of a reference `[s1 ref 147-150]` that link to another sheet, however, these appear in the uploaded XLSX as `[11]` which is completely wrong, but they link to the correct cells on the other end.

My main issue is that I have to keep working on the Windows 10 version and periodically upload to Google Drive but it gets mangled every time.

Has anyone found this to happen and is there a solution to stop it from happening? I do think that the `[s1 ref 147-150]` links mentioned above were probably originally clones of `[11]` and this caused the anomaly somehow but I've no idea how to get rid of it.

I've just found a partial fix and part of the problem:

I found that if I erase the secondary cells containing `[11]` and retype them and regenerate the hyperlinks the anomalies go away. However, if I try to delete the first occurrence of `[11]` in the first sheet it appears in and retypes, I see that no matter what I do, the text will always be underlined as if Excel thinks its a hyperlink. This is wrong. So, it must be the source of the problem. This would explain why Google Docs shows `papers!a1` instead of the link. This further suggests that Excel contains the bug and not Google Drive.

Comment: I've since changed the offending cell and cleaned it and uploaded the file to office 365. I was using Excel 2010 and see that it renders fine in office 365. After changing the offending cell the problems are way more pronounced now in Google Drive (Docs). I'm now returning to the conclusion that Google Drive is the offender and not Excel 2010.

Comment: The problem exists in viewing the document and using google docs. The problem goes away if downloaded from google docs to a windows 7 or 10 machine. So the rendering is definitely being mangled by Google.